# Hadoop API throws an error when trying to initialize cluster in order to use DistCp

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, cloudera

I'm trying to use the Hadoop API to do a Distributed Copy using the DistCp class, but it throws an error when trying to connect to the cluster. I have tried to change the configuration files of hadoop and hdfs but it doesn't seem to work. I'm testing the app on the latest Cloudera Quickstart

I run this command to execute the class. 
java -cp myjar com.keedio.hadoop.Mover

package com.keedio.hadoop;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp;

import org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCpOptionSwitch;
import org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCpOptions;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import java.util.Collections;


public class Mover {

public static void main(String args []) {

 try {
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(new Configuration());
  FileSystem fs2= FileSystem.get(java.net.URI.create("file:///"),new 
  Configuration());
  DistCpOptions distCpOptions=new DistCpOptions(new Path("file:/Users/jvasquez/Desktop/ficheros1"),new Path("file:/Users/jvasquez/Desktop/ficheros2"));
String argumentos [] = {"file:////Users/jvasquez/Desktop/ficheros1","file:///Users/jvasquez/Desktop/ficheros2"};


Configuration conf=new Configuration();

conf.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

DistCp distCp= new DistCp(conf,distCpOptions);

ToolRunner.run(distCp,argumentos);




}
 catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();

}


}

}
```

This is the error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createMetaFolderPath(DistCp.java:471)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.<init>(DistCp.java:107)
at com.keedio.hadoop.Mover.main(Mover.java:48)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved it, it resulted to be that i just had to launch the application as a mapreduce application using the command hadoop jar.